# Use of unresolved identifier 'FlurryAdInterstitial'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, flurry

I am trying to integrate `Flurry` `Interstitial Ads` using
   `cocoapods` in `Swift` and `Xcode 7.1.1`.

I am following this documentation from developer yahoo site
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/ios/#tab=0

The instructions don't seem to be working for me. First, I get this error in my AppDelegate.swift:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Flurry'

Then I found a closed issue in the Flurry Github repository 
https://github.com/flurry/Flurry-iOS-SDK/issues/3

I was able to remove the error using

```
import Flurry_iOS_SDK
```

But now `FlurryAdInterstitial` also has same kind of error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'FlurryAdInterstitial'

I am not able to remove this linking error using `import Flurry_iOS_SDK`. If I import Flurry_iOS_SDK I get this linking error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryAdInterstitial", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.FlurryAdInterstitial in ViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've also made a demo project in Github to reproduce this linking error. 
https://github.com/rishi420/TestSwiftFlurryAd

Just download this repository and build in Xcode 7.x, you should able to get this error.

Comment: Opened an issue https://github.com/flurry/Flurry-iOS-SDK/issues/18#issuecomment-171512734

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the github issue - need to specify -all_load linker flag in the Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryAds podspec. Here is a working patch (hopefully will be merged into the oficial spec soon, or they will solve in other ways):

```
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK', :git => "git@github.com:justadreamer/Flurry-iOS-SDK.git"
```

Comment: Thanks. But `pod install` fails. here is the log: `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: you may change my demo github project

Comment: yes I'm getting the same permission error.  Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.