# Flurry Ads integration issue when using cocoapds

Tags: ios9, cocoapods, flurry

I am using Cocoapods to integrate **Flurry Ads** in my project as per the instructions on the [Flurry Developer Documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/ios/).

I have my podfile as below:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Foo' do
    pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'
    pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryAds'
end
```

I am **not** using a Bridging Header since in **Cocoapods 0.39** we can use `use_frameworks!` to avoid the bridging header. I have set the '**Build Active Architecture**' to **Yes for Debug** and **No for Release**.

This is the error I get: `_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryXXXXXX referenced from FooViewController`, `linker command failed with exit code 1`

[image]

Comment: I am having same problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/34478279/1378447
Opened an issue https://github.com/flurry/Flurry-iOS-SDK/issues/18#issuecomment-171512734

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the github issue https://github.com/flurry/Flurry-iOS-SDK/issues/18 and in this SO answer: [Use of unresolved identifier 'FlurryAdInterstitial'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478279/use-of-unresolved-identifier-flurryadinterstitial/34839705#34839705): need to specify -all_load linker flag in the Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryAds podspec. Here is a working patch (hopefully will be merged into the oficial spec soon, or they will solve in other ways):

```
pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK', :git => "git@github.com:justadreamer/Flurry-iOS-SDK.git"
```

Hope this will save you some time

Comment: Thanks for the effort, though I would wait for the official response. I have contacted the Flurry support and they said they are looking into it.

Answer (score -1):

I integrate Flurry from Scratch using your CocoaPods Settings.
You have to add some libraries and frameworks which are requires to run app successfully.

Please attach below given Frameworks and libraries as given in Images:

```
libz.1.1.3.tbd
libz.1.2.5.tbd
libz.1.tbd
libz.tbd
SystemConfiguration.ramework
MediaPlayer.framework
AdSupport.framework
libFlurry_7.3.0.a
libFlurryAds_7.3.0.a
Security.framework
Flurry_iOS_SDK.framework
Pods_ProjectName.framework
```

Add this line to AppDelegate.swift

```
//  AppDelegate.swift

import Flurry_iOS_SDK

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Flurry.startSession("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return true
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So these are to be added to the Main project and not to the Pods project?

Comment: Add it to Target settings.

Comment: Target of the Main project or the Flurry target of the Pods project?

Comment: Target of Main Project. If you find any issue then let me know.

Comment: I tried with all the settings above, still the same issue :(. I did not add the `libFlurry*.a`, because thats what I'd do without Cocoapods. The whole point of using Cocoapods is that I don't have to manually include the dependencies.

Comment: So are you using CocoaPods or not ?

Comment: Yes, I am. That is why I do not want to include the Flurry libs directly as in the screenshot. But apart from that I still cannot build with the above settings you have shown.